# How to split one var string in two float vars

Tags: java

How to split this var:

```
String x = "center=-34.604632,-58.375798";
```

Into:

```
float long = "-34.604632";
float lati = "-58.375798";
```

Answer (score 2):

Split the string by the equals mark:

```
String x = "center=-34.604632,-58.375798"
String[] xSplit = x.split("=");
```

Longitude and latitude are in the second half

```
String longAndLat = xSplit[1];
```

Split the new string by the comma:

```
String[] longAndLatSplit = longAndLat.split(",");
```

Convert the two strings into floats

```
float longitude = Float.parseFloat(longAndLatSplit[0]);
float latitude = Float.parseFloat(longAndLatSplit[1]);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
 String loc = "center=-34.604632,-58.375798";
```

//First split by '=', that would give you 'center' and '-34.604632,-58.375798' .Split that again by ','. Then parse it to get a float value

```
String[] locSplit = loc.split("=")[1].split(",");
float latitude = Float.parseFloat(locSplit[0]);
float longitude = Float.parseFloat(locSplit[1]);
System.out.println(latitude);
System.out.println(longitude);
```